# Pandas - sum values from dateranges for every day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame from a project schedule:

```
Task    Start        End      Staff
Task 1  2020-1-1    2020-1-4   11
Task 2  2020-1-2    2020-1-4   12
Task 3  2020-1-4    2020-1-6    2
...
```

Desired output:

```
day         staff
2020-1-1    11
2020-1-2    23
2020-1-3    23
2020-1-4    25
2020-1-5    14
```

So far, I am using `.iterrows()` to go through the complete df.

```
day = timedelta(days=1)
new_rows = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    start = row.Start
    while start <= row.End:
        newrow = row.copy()
        newrow['day'] = start
        new_rows.append(newrow.values)

        start += day
df_staff = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns= newrow.index).reset_index()
```

Works good, just like to know, if there are better/faster ways. Right now, my df has 10 000 rows, but could expand.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Btw, a bit surprised with downvote - because my opinion nice question - data, expected output, code what OP try. No reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are always necessary loops, because working with ranges per rows. One possible solution is use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with `concat` and `sum`:

```
df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Staff,pd.date_range(r.Start, r.End)) 
                   for r in df.itertuples()])
         .sum(level=0)
         .rename_axis('day')
         .reset_index(name='staff'))
print (df1)
         day  staff
0 2020-01-01     11
1 2020-01-02     23
2 2020-01-03     23
3 2020-01-04     25
4 2020-01-05      2
5 2020-01-06      2
```

Another solution with list comprehension:

```
zipped = zip(df.Start, df.End, df.Staff)

df1 = (pd.DataFrame([(x, v) for s, e, v in zipped for x in pd.date_range(s, e)], 
                    columns=['day','staff'])
        .groupby('day', as_index=False)['staff'].sum())

print (df1)
         day  staff
0 2020-01-01     11
1 2020-01-02     23
2 2020-01-03     23
3 2020-01-04     25
4 2020-01-05      2
5 2020-01-06      2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, and really fast. Which one would be the best to go, if there would be a aditional columns? Say, you want to keep all the other data in a row?  I tried  my solution with `.itertuples()` too, but to no succes.

Comment: @nanuuq for all rows is possible first part of solution - create default index if necessary `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` and then `df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.Start, r.End)) 
                   for r in df.itertuples()])
          .rename_axis('day')
          .reset_index(name='idx')
          .join(df, on='idx')
          .drop('idx', axis=1))
print (df1)` Then if aggregate is necessary for each column aggregate function like `df1 = df1.groupby('day', as_index=False).agg({'Task':'first', 'Staff':'sum'})` for avoid lost column

Comment: perfect. Works really fast. Thanks